# Como extrair dados a partir de textos simples não estandardizados?

Tags: python, python-2.7, análise-de-dados

Gostaria de extrair campos para uma base de dados a partir de ficheiros de texto. No entanto os campos estão posicionados de formas diferentes em cada texto sendo difícil obter os valores por métodos comuns, exemplo:

ficheiro 1:

```
PROVA: 2º Corta Mato    

LOCAL:  Pinhal da Paz
ORGANIZAÇÃO:    
AAP 

ESTADO TEMPO: Bom   
DATA:   28-01-2007
```

ficheiro 2:

```
PROVA: MEGA SPRINTER         LOCAL: E.B.I. DE ARRIFES
ASSOCIACAO: AASM/SDSM
TEMPO: Nublado c/ vento
DIA: 22 de Março de 2006
```

ficheiro 3:

```
AASM
ESTADO TEMPO: Nublado/Ventoso c/ alguma chuva
DATA: 19 de Novembro de 2005
1º Triatlo Técnico + P. de Preparação
C. D. DAS LARANJEIRAS
```

São milhares de ficheiros, multiplos campos por ficheiro e cada campo pode ter um ou multiplos valores por texto, logo fazer a extração de dados à mão está fora de questão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para esse efeito criei o pacote [MassTextExtractor](https://github.com/equidna/MassTextExtractor) para o carregar basta instalar, através do pip, na linha de comandos:

```
sudo pip install MassTextExtractor
```

Um exemplo da sua utilização para os campos "local" e "prova", das amostras dos ficheiros demonstrados, seria:

```
from MassTextExtractor import TextsParser

# marcar linhas do campo prova
file_dirs = ["./ficheiro_1.txt", "./ficheiro_2.txt", "./ficheiro_3.txt"]
flags = ["Triatlo", "PROVA:"]
prova = TextsParser(file_dirs, flags)

# limpar partes da linha
prova.switchers = [("PROVA:", "")]
prova.switch_texts_field_lines()

# partir parte da linha
prova.breakers = [("LOCAL", 0)]
prova.break_texts_field_lines()


# marcar linhas do campo local
file_dirs = ["./ficheiro_1.txt", "./ficheiro_2.txt", "./ficheiro_3.txt"]
flags = ["LARANJEIRAS", "LOCAL:"]
local = TextsParser(file_dirs, flags)

# partir parte da linha
local.breakers = [("LOCAL:", 1)]
local.break_texts_field_lines()

# limpar partes da linha
local.switchers = [("LOCAL:", "")]
local.switch_texts_field_lines()


print prova.return_texts_field_lines()
print local.return_texts_field_lines()
```

Pode parecer excessivamente pedante, no entanto, creio que pode ser bastante útil quando usado como um último recurso para obter dados de grandes quantidades de texto semi desestruturado.